# origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: cors, koa

I'm getting the standard CORS error that everyone has probably experienced at one time or another but haven't been able to get it to go away:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3030/feedback-detail/comment' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
ApiService.js:82  POST http://localhost:3030/feedback-detail/comment net::ERR_FAILED 
ApiService.js:86 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error submitting comment at addComment (ApiService.js:86:1)
```

I have tried setting localhost:3000 in cors, as well as wild card but I get the same error:

```
app.use(cors({origin: '*'})); or app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));
```

I also tried setting the Access Control header in the request:

```
export const addComment = async (comment) => {
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(comment)
  };

try {
    const response = await fetch(URL + '/feedback-detail/comment', options);
    const data = response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Error submitting comment')
  }
}
```

I also have a addRequest api request that is setup basically the same and it works fine. So unsure why this is happening. I was able to just use app.use(cors()) without an origin for that one.

Server side:

Model:

```
exports.postComment = (comment) => {
  const sql = 'INSERT INTO comments (request_id, comment_id, content, username, name, image, replying_to) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)';
  const values = [comment.id, comment.comment_id, comment.content, comment.username, comment.name, comment.image, comment.replying_to];
  return pool.query(sql, values);
}
```

Controller:

```
exports.addComment = async ctx => {
  try {
    await requestModel.postComment(ctx.request.body);
    ctx.status = 201;
  } catch (error) {
    ctx.throw(500, error);
  }
}
```

router:

```
router.post('/feedback-detail/comment', addComment)
```

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * belongs on the server side, not the client side.

Comment: Well shouldn't it not be needed if I use the following?

app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue with the package I was using:

koa-cors

Now we should be using @koa/cors

https://github.com/koajs/cors

With that installed then app.use(cors()) works fine.